# Transaction and catch block

Tags: java, transactions

What will happen if second transaction is rolled back (i.e. method3()) ? Will first transaction rollback?

// no transactional method

```
method1()
{
  try{
       method2(); // transactional
       method3(); // transactional and fails due to exception
  }
  catch {
    return "error message";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, if `method3()` fails, `method2()`'s transaction will NOT roll back because they are 2 different transactions.

Note : Even if method1 was transactional, it will not ensure atomicity of the whole operation (method2 + method3) because you are catching the exception.